# How to delete nested property using JS spread rest destruction?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

Trying to delete multiple properties usign spread operator rest destruction, so drugName is being removed but i have nested object `mailPrice.copayEmployer` that is not getting destructed any idea what is implemented wrong ?

main.js

```
const transformedResponse = transformResponse(response);
  const loggerResponse = transformedResponse.map(
      ({drugName, mailPrice.copayEmployer, ...rest}) => rest
  );
```

transformedResponse

```
[{
        "isBrand": true,
        "drugName": "Lipitor",
        "drugStrength": "80 mg",
        "drugForm": "Tablet",
        "mailPrice": {
            "copayEmployer": 0
        }
    }, {
        "isBrand": true,
        "drugName": "Metformin",
        "drugStrength": "500 mg",
        "drugForm": "Tablet",
        "mailPrice": {
            "copayEmployer": 50
        }
    }

]
```

Comment: What is the result you want to achieve? You want to keep the `mailPrice` property, but remove the `copayEmployer` property inside it?

Comment: @Barmar yes thats correct just want to remove mailPrice.copayEmployer and keep the rest of the object

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can do this with a single variable. You need a nested `...rest` variable inside the `mailPrice` object, and then you have to reconstruct the object.

```js
const transformedResponse = [{
  "isBrand": true,
  "drugName": "Lipitor",
  "drugStrength": "80 mg",
  "drugForm": "Tablet",
  "mailPrice": {
    "copayEmployer": 0,
  }
}, {
  "isBrand": true,
  "drugName": "Metformin",
  "drugStrength": "500 mg",
  "drugForm": "Tablet",
  "mailPrice": {
    "copayEmployer": 50
  }
}];

const loggerResponse = transformedResponse.map(
  ({
    drugName,
    mailPrice: { copayEmployer, ...mailPriceRest},
    ...rest
  }) => ({mailPrice: mailPriceRest, ...rest})
);

console.log(loggerResponse);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you destructure nested object's:

```
.map(({ drugName, mailPrice: { copayEmployer, ...restMail }, ...rest }) => ({ mailPrice: { ...restMail }, ...rest});
```

Comment: I don't think this will do what he wants. `...rest` won't contain the rest of the `mailPrice` object.

Comment: yeah this is deleting complete object of mailPrice that i dont want

Comment: Fixed now, any better?

Comment: @Jack Bashford its not happening , is there any other approach instead of spread operator ?